# Is there anyway to kill "Administrator cmd.exe" using taskill on batch programming?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taskkill

I am using the command,

```
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
```

using above command it will kill cmd.exe windows which are all open.

**But, my question is, How do I kill administrator command prompt using taskkill command ?**

*above mentioned command doesn't working for elevated cmd.exe*

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt as administrator and then execute taskkill /IM cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, you need an administrator prompt in order to be able to do this.
I just tried following command:

```
taskkill /S System /U "administrator" /IM cmd.exe
```

... but I received "ERROR: The RPC server is unavailable.". Next point will be the explanation of that error message and how to handle it, or maybe it works for you?